# many if condition -- if with array condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new with vue.js, I have a question about my code. the console of symptom just appear but the disease is not. [console of symptom and disease](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnL5c.png).
So about the condition is the user selected some symptoms, thus system show the disease name based on the symptoms**

```
<v-container>
            <p>{{ symptom }}</p>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Diarrheal"
              value="Diarrheal"
            >
            </v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Vomit"
              value="Vomit"
            ></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Red Eyes"
              value="Red Eyes"
            ></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Tiredness"
              value="Tiredness"
            ></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Dehydrated"
              value="Dehydrated"
            ></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Greasy Stools"
              value="Greasy Stools"
            ></v-checkbox>
            <v-checkbox
              v-model="symptom"
              label="Swollen Lymph nodes"
              value="Swollen Lymph nodes"
            ></v-checkbox>
    <v-btn color="primary" @click="handleSubmit"> Submit </v-btn>
   </v-container>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
components: {},
data() {
  return {
    symptom: [],
    Disease: "",  
  };
},
methods: {
  back() {
    this.$emit("update:cat", null);
  },
  async handleSubmit() {
      if(this.symptom === ["Vomit","Swollen Lymph nodes","Red Eyes","Tiredness"]){
        this.Disease = "Cat Scratch Disease";
      }
      if(this.symptom === ["Diarrheal","Greasy Stools","Dehydrated"]){
        this.Disease = "Giardiasis";
      }
      if(this.symptom === ["Diarrheal"]){
        this.Disease = "Campylobacter";
      }
    console.log(this.symptom)
    console.log(this.Disease)
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Thank You for your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can map your data and use `find` and `every`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      symptoms: ['Diarrheal','Vomit','Red Eyes', 'Tiredness', 'Dehydrated', 'Greasy Stools', 'Swollen Lymph nodes'],
      symptom: [],
      Disease: "",
      diseases: [{symptom: ["Vomit","Swollen Lymph nodes","Red Eyes","Tiredness"], disease: "Cat Scratch Disease"}, {symptom: ["Diarrheal","Greasy Stools","Dehydrated"], disease: "Giardiasis"}, {symptom: ["Diarrheal"], disease: "Campylobacter"}]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleSubmit() {
      const res = this.diseases.find(d => 
        d.symptom.length === this.symptom.length && d.symptom.every(e => 
          this.symptom.includes(e)))?.disease
      this.Disease = res ? res : ""
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <p>{{ symptom }}</p>
        <v-btn color="primary" @click="handleSubmit"> Submit </v-btn>
        <strong>{{Disease}}</strong>
        <div v-for="sympt in symptoms" :key="sympt">
          <v-checkbox
            v-model="symptom"
            :label="sympt"
            :value="sympt"
          >
          </v-checkbox>
        </div>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can see there is one drawback in this solution, If you select the multiple checkboxes and if any of the selected symptoms match with any of the symptoms array that we have. then it returns true and show that one

Comment: @Rohìt Jíndal hey mate, did you try the snippet, I updated my answer in first one I forgot to also compare the length

Comment: First thing, I am not the one who downvoted. I just noticed so commented. Yeah it's working fine now.

Answer (score -1):

The way you are comparing your array is wrong, you can do something like this:

```
// we are checking values and length to make sure nothing is more or less than we expect
if (this.symptom.length === 4 && ["Vomit","Swollen Lymph nodes","Red Eyes","Tiredness"].every(item => this.symptom.includes(item))) {
    this.Disease = "Cat Scratch Disease"
}
if (this.symptom.length === 3 && ["Diarrheal","Greasy Stools","Dehydrated"].every(item => this.symptom.includes(item))) {
    this.Disease = "Giardiasis"
}
```